# Detect when a div is touching top jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect when a div is at the top of the page with Jquery/Javascript. Anyone any idea's where I might start?

Comment: you mean that div offset top == 0?

Comment: Not sure, I'd just like to change it's css when it is at the top of the document. I don't really have any experience of javascript or jquery!

Comment: *"Not sure, I'd just like to change it's css when it is at the top of the document"* - you mean when it's *scrolled* to the top of the window?

Comment: Yep, so once it scrolled and hits the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the scroll event using jQuery, and every time it changes, get the offset value of the div and compare it with 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function like this:

```
function elementAtViewportTop(elem) {
    if(!elem || typeof elem !== "object") return false;
    if(elem instanceof jQuery) elem = elem[0];

    var elemClientRect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (elemClientRect.top <= 0 && elemClientRect.top > -(elemClientRect.height));
}
```

`elem.getBoundingClientRect().top` will be zero if the element reaches the top of the window ([getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)).
When you add an event listener for scroll to the window and call that function every time on your element, it will work fine:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/bvD9R/)

Comment: Does the fact I have stuff positioned absolutely and relatively affect this? Doesn't seem to be working for me.